# An equation with square root

Tags: linear-algebra

$$2x+\sqrt{1-3x}=0$$
I know thats a basic task, but I forgot how to do such simple equations. Should I just switch 2x to the other side, and square both sides?

Comment: Yes, that's a good place to start.  Beware, however, that when both sides of an equation are squared, the solutions to the _transformed_ equation may not _all_ work in your original equation.  Always check your answers for that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but note that squaring both sides can introduce fictitious solutions.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
2x+ \sqrt{1-3x} = 0 
\end{align}
leads to
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-3x} &= -2x \\
1-3x &= 4x^{2}
\end{align}
where both sides were squared. Now this is $4 x^{2} + 3x -1= 0$. The solutions of which are $x = -1, 1/4$. The first result can be checked and yields $-2 + \sqrt{1 + 3} = -2 + 2 = 0$ which is correct. The solution $x = 1/4$ does not satisfy the equation and is to be excluded.